# non-grain options in sourdough starter

Tags: yeast, sourdough, dried-fruit

Is there any reason not to try adding dried fruit to a sourdough starter? The reason I'm imagining is that different sorts of yeast live on dried fruit vs on grains. This could turn out to be delicious or terrible. As well I've never seen sugar added to a starter so I'm curious what the dried fruit sugars would do. Is there any info on this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon to use pineapple juice, grapes...berries...really all sorts of fruits,  as a source of yeast/bacteria for a sourdough starter.  Dried fruit, such as apricot is also used. So, there is no reason you can't give it a go.